# Wrapping Python int/float objects

Tags: python, concurrency, metaprogramming

I am working on a Python concurrency framework (I know, YACF) and would like to be able to return variables as Futures, but without the user noticing it.

Right now I am doing:

```
x = someAsyncMethod(args)
print "Return value is %d" % x.get_value( )
```

Because the method return a Future object, but I would like it to be:

```
x = someAsyncMethod(args)
print "Return value is %d" % x
```

But still have the .get_value( ) of x invoked. Therefore I would like to Proxy wrap Python objects including int. Something like __get__, but so that if ProxyInt was a proxy for int and I did:

```
x = ProxyInt(10)
print x
```

or

```
n = x
```

My "__get__" method would be called and do some magic before doing "return 10"

Comment: FYI: I believe the `__get__` method works with descriptors, but it doesn't do what you want here.  The descriptor has to be an attribute of a class... i.e. you'd have to access the value through an attribute for `__get__` to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class I(object):
...   def __int__(self):
...     return 42
... 
>>> i = I()
>>> print '%d' % i
42
>>> class F(object):
...   def __float__(self):
...     return 3.14
... 
>>> f = F()
>>> print '%f' % f
3.140000
>>> class S(object):
...   def __str__(self):
...     return 'foo'
... 
>>> s = S()
>>> print s
foo
```

Comment: Whoa, that was fast. Thank you. I was not aware of \_\_str\_\_ lesser know cousins \_\_int\_\_ and \_\_float\_\_

Comment: And `__complex__()`. Can't forget that one.

Answer (score 0):

You could override `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` (whichever suites your needs the best) to perform the "magic" on, for instance, the first attribute access of the proxy.

Comment: Overriding these two would not work in my case, since I need a trigger for the access to the object itself, not just it's proprties. (But I use them for other things in the framework)